# How can I write a list of lists into a txt file?

Tags: python

I have a list of 16 elements, and each element is another 500 elements long.  I would like to write this to a txt file so I no longer have to create the list from a simulation.  How can I do this, and then access the list again?

Comment: Have you looked at `pickle`? What have you tried so far? Not sure if you are concerned with the list being in a text file, or with being able to access a previously generated list without regenerating each time.

Comment: Looked at cpickle and found a good way to do it.  Thanks guys.

Comment: @DemetriP if you want plain txt file, please check out my answer below.

Comment: JSON is another option for saving the data structure and that has the advantage of being readable by other devices, such as humans.

Answer (score 9):

Pickle will work, but the shortcoming is that it is a Python-specific binary format. Save as JSON for easy reading and re-use in other applications:

```
import json

LoL = [ range(5), list("ABCDE"), range(5) ]

with open('Jfile.txt','w') as myfile:
    json.dump(LoL,myfile)
```

The file now contains:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

To get it back later:

```
with open('Jfile.txt','r') as infile:
    newList = json.load(infile)

print newList
```

Answer (score 6):

To store it:

```
import cPickle

savefilePath = 'path/to/file'
with open(savefilePath, 'w') as savefile:
  cPickle.dump(myBigList, savefile)
```

To get it back:

```
import cPickle

savefilePath = 'path/to/file'
with open(savefilePath) as savefile:
  myBigList = cPickle.load(savefile)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look pickle Object serialization. With pickle you can serialize your list and then save it to a text file. Later you can 'unpickle' the data from the text file. The data will be unpickled to a list and you can use it again in python.  @inspectorG4dget beat me to the answer so take a look at.

Answer (score 0):

While `pickle` is certainly a good option, for this particular question I would prefer simply saving it into a csv or just plain txt file with 16 columns using `numpy`.

```
import numpy as np

# here I use list of 3 lists as an example
nlist = 3

# generating fake data `listoflists`
listoflists = []
for i in xrange(3) :
    listoflists.append([i]*500)

# save it into a numpy array
outarr = np.vstack(listoflists)
# save it into a file
np.savetxt("test.dat", outarr.T)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do recommend cPickle in this case, but you should take some "extra" steps:

- ZLIB the output.
- Encode or encrypt it.

By doing this you have these advantages:

- ZLIB will reduce its size.
- Encrypting may keep pickling hijacks off.

Yes, pickle is not safe! See [this.](http://lincolnloop.com/blog/2013/mar/22/playing-pickle-security)