# Python read dictionary as an argument to main method

Tags: python, dictionary, program-entry-point

I am calling a python like as below :-

> python doSomething.py arg1 arg2 {'someKey': 'someValue',
> 'anotherKey': 'anotherValue'}

```
import sys
def main(args):
    if len(args) == 0:
        print("error")

    else:
        argument1 = args[0]
        argument2 = args[1]
        # third is dict
        customdict = args[2]
        print(customdict["someKey"])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Gives the below error

> string indices must be integers, not str

I want to get values like `customdict["someKey"]`

Comment: Use proper options, which is far more standard to use on the command line: `python doSomething.py arg1 arg2 --somekey someValue --anotherKey anotherValue`. Then convert those options to a dict. Do not try and put Python syntax on the command line: they (Python and the command line/shell) are two different things.

Comment: Tip: avoid using built in functions and such as variable names; in your case, avoid using `dict` as a variable name. This will at some point cause problems down the road.

Comment: what if more key vals..I will end up in more key vals as arguments...

Comment: Note that your error is caused by yet something else, but since there is code missing (how do you call `main`; how do you retrieve the command line arguments?), we can't tell for certain how to fix that.

Comment: If you want more key-value pairs, you should consider using a configuration file.

Comment: The question here is really "how do I communicate complex data from the command line to a program?", which is more of a question about how to use the operating system well than it is about programming. I would try asking on superuser.com instead.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I think that is a step too far: there's still a programming question here, and not directly a question on how to use an OS.

Comment: @00 I have updated executable code

Comment: `print(customdict["someKey"])` causes an error, because you assigned `customdict` to `args[2]`, and `args[2]` is simply a string. One of the several strings pass as command line arguments to your program.

Comment: ok I get now..so I am getting a string not dictionary from the command line...is there a way to convert?

Comment: Do not try to convert the string to dict: you have far less control over what is in the actual dict than by using options. Besides, trying to do things your way, your program behaves far differently than all other programs out there in the world.

Comment: You might try importing as a quoted string and then use json parsing within your program to convert that string to a python entity. `--arg " {'someKey': 'someValue', 'anotherKey': 'anotherValue'}"`  https://stackoverflow.com/a/19460932/1681480

Answer (score 0):

Avoid trying to use Python syntax and code on the command line. The shell and Python are different things (and serve different purposes).

Instead, use proper options. Depending on your operating system, something like:

`python doSomething.py arg1 arg2 --somekey someValue --anotherKey anotherValue`

then convert those options in your dict inside your Python program.

If you end up using many options, you may consider using a configuration file instead, with key-value pairs. A simple `ini` type configuration file can already suffice.

For both (command line arguments and configuration files), prefer to use existing modules that come with Python. Default modules are [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) and [`configParser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html). It may take a bit getting used to them, but your program will behave more standard then, and is easier to understand for other people.

Finally, the error you are seeing is because of a different thing: you assigned `customdict` to `args[2]`, and `args[2]` is simply a string (the string may happen to be `"{'someKey': 'someValue', 'anotherKey': 'anotherValue'}"`, or more likely `"{'someKey':"`, but you can't use it as a dict).